# Will an old Pentium 4-based server run Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, dell-poweredge

I have a Dell PowerEdge 400sc with 4GB DDR 400, Pentium 4 3.2GHz. 
It's an old server I would like to re-purpose as a domain controller/web server/file server for home intranet - mostly as a learning tool.

Would it run Windows Server 2008 R2 (which is 64-bit only)?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the CPU model number?

Comment: Renan, not sure as it is powered down. I will check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 400SC came with 32 and 64 bit processors.  If you have a 64 bit processor, your machine is more that capable of running Server 2008 R2.  Check out [Microsoft's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2008_R2) requirements for server 2008.